# Laravel Model insert second time only works if browser is restarted

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am building an URL shortener.

I 301 redirect the page visit, but before I save the visit in my database. But my problem is, that the page visit is only saved once. If I visit the same shortlink a second time, the visit is not saved. Is this normal? I get a second record if I restart the browser.

Personaly I think the browser caches the redirect and ignores the inserting into my db.

Do you have an answer for this?

```
public function redirect($link)
    {
        $link = Link::where('shortlink', clean($link))->first();
        $protocol = ($link->protocol == '1') ? 'https://' : 'http://';

        $link->visits()->create([
            'browserName' => \Browser::browserName(),
            'browserFamily' => \Browser::browserFamily(),
        ]);
        return redirect($protocol . $link->longlink, 301);

    }
```

Comment: 301 is a permanent redirect which the browser caches and since the first request any next one will directly go to the redirect url without touching your server.

Comment: So 302 would fix it? But Crawler like facebook and whatsapp would still follow it?

Comment: Most likely 302 or 307 should be fine, you need to test with multiple browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 302 instead.

**Status 301** means that the resource (page) is moved permanently to a new location. The client/browser **will not request the original location for the second time** and will simply use the new location from now on.

Status 302 means that the resource is temporarily located somewhere else and the client/browser **will always request the original location**.